# Multiple User login form for excel vba

Tags: excel, authentication, vba

I have followed [this guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88d8c0/create-login-application-in-excel-macro-using-visual-basic-f/) and found out that if my username and password is both wrong, it will throw a runtime error:

> "6" Overflow error.

However, I have tried using the code below:

```
ElseIf Username <> u And Password <> p Then
    MsgBox "Username & Password not matched", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
Exit Do
```

I tried using this code but even if my username and password match it still throw the below MsgBox.

[image]
 Code here

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Username As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim u As String
    Dim p As String
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" And Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter username and password.", vbOKOnly
    ElseIf Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the username ", vbOKOnly
    ElseIf Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the Password ", vbOKOnly
    Else
    Username = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
    Password = Trim(TextBox2.Text)
    i = 1
    Do While Cells(1, 1).Value <> ""
    j = 1
    u = Cells(i, j).Value
    j = j + 1
    p = Cells(i, j).Value
If Username = u And Password = p And Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail" Then
    MsgBox "Your Account temporarily locked", vbCritical
Exit Do

ElseIf Username = u And Password = p Then
    Call clr
    'LoginFlag = True
    Unload Me
    MsgBox ("Welcome " + u + ", :)")
Exit Do

ElseIf Username <> u And Password = p Then
    MsgBox "Username not matched", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
Exit Do
ElseIf Username = u And Password <> p Then
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail" Then
    MsgBox "Your account is blocked", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
Exit Do

ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value < 2 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid password", vbCritical
    Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4) + 1
Exit Do
Else
    Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4) + 1
    Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail"
    'Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
    Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Exit Do
End If

ElseIf Username <> u And Password <> p Then
    MsgBox "Username & Password not match", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
Exit Do

Else
    i = i + 1
End If
Loop
End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, next time use the "code formatting button" `{}` to format your code! Also, please improve your question by including the *text* of the error message, and not only a screenshot. Also, if something says "enter image description here", *please enter an image description*. It's really not all that hard to ask a properly made question!

Comment: Also note that this is the worst possible example of a password dialog. With the password being part of the unencrypted data its meant to protect. Never even think about using something like this!

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't be certain - but my guess is that you have the 3 lines you have shown us within a loop.  So, as soon as you hit a username that isn't the one you are looking up **and** the password isn't the one you are looking up, you display the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following may work better:

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Username As String
    Dim Password As String
    'Use a variable to flag whether the userid is valid or not
    Dim useridValid As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    'Dim j As Integer
    Dim u As String
    Dim p As String
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" And Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter username and password.", vbOKOnly
    ElseIf Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter the username ", vbOKOnly
    ElseIf Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter the Password ", vbOKOnly
    Else
        Username = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
        Password = Trim(TextBox2.Text)
        useridValid = False
        i = 1
        'Don't perform a loop which is dependent on a fixed cell that
        'isn't updated within the loop
        'Use a variable row counter instead
        'Do While Cells(1, 1).Value <> ""
        Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
            'There is no point in having a variable simply to specify a
            'column that doesn't change
            'j = 1
            u = Cells(i, "A").Value
            'j = j + 1
            p = Cells(i, "B").Value
            'Only perform tests once a valid username has been found
            If Username = u Then
                'Flag that we have found the userid
                useridValid = True
                If Cells(i, "C").Value = "fail" Then
                    'Too many login attempts
                    MsgBox "Your Account temporarily locked", vbCritical
                ElseIf Password = p Then
                    'Clear invalid attempts count
                    Cells(i, 4).Value = 0
                    Cells(i, 3).Value = ""

                    Call clr
                    Unload Me
                    MsgBox ("Welcome " + u + ", :)")
                Else
                    'Invalid password
                    'Increment failed attempts counter
                    Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4) + 1
                    'Lock account on 3rd failed password
                    If Cells(i, 4).Value > 2 Then
                        'lock the account
                        Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail"
                        'Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
                        Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        'Tell the user that password was invalid and now locked
                        MsgBox "Invalid password - account locked", vbCritical
                    Else
                        'Tell the user that password was invalid
                        MsgBox "Invalid password", vbCritical
                    End If
                End If
                'Don't check any further usernames
                Exit Do
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        'If the flag saying that we found the userid isn't set, display
        'a message
        If Not useridValid Then
            MsgBox "Username not matched", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
        End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: It is definitely a bad idea to hold passwords in clear text within a worksheet.  It is too easy for people to obtain the entire list.

Comment: Thanks alot! i guess that helps (for now i guess i would try to understand everyline means haha). Yes im aware that its too easy for people to obtain the entire list of users but i think i would want to smoke out for now as im still super noob programmer :(.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the code hasn't been catered for the case when both `Username` as well as `Password` fail, and it's an infinite loop `Do While Cells(1, 1).Value <> ""`. So the value of counter `i`, whose data type is set as `Integer`, keeps increasing, and once it exceeds the limit of 32,767, it generates the `Overflow` error.

In support of my above assertion, consider these arguments in your code:

Condition 1 - Login Status is "fail":

```
If Username = u And Password = p And Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail" Then
```

Condition 2 - both `Username` and `Password` match:

```
ElseIf Username = u And Password = p Then
```

Condition 3 - `Username` didn't match:

```
ElseIf Username <> u And Password = p Then
```

Condition 4 - `Password` didn't match:

```
ElseIf Username = u And Password <> p Then
```

**Solution:**

We need to change the infinite loop to finite, i.e. it will stop once it reaches to the blank cell - so it will be like `Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""`.

Also, we may add to the above, the condition when both `Username` and `Password` fail, which you have correctly identified, but I suspect, if it's still throwing error, it needs to be put at the right place, i.e. just after the `Do While` loop.

Another small correction - `i` should start with 2 instead of 1, as we want to lookup from the 2<sup>nd</sup> row.

Therefore, let's put it all together:

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Username As String, Password As String, i As Integer, j As Integer, u As String, p As String
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" And Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter username and password.", vbOKOnly
    ElseIf Trim(TextBox1.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter the username ", vbOKOnly
    ElseIf Trim(TextBox2.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter the Password ", vbOKOnly
    Else
        Username = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
        Password = Trim(TextBox2.Text)
        i = 2
        Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
            j = 1
            u = Cells(i, j).Value
            j = j + 1
            p = Cells(i, j).Value
            If Username = u And Password = p And Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail" Then
                MsgBox "Your Account temporarily locked", vbCritical
            Exit Do
            ElseIf Username = u And Password = p Then
                Call clr
                'LoginFlag = True
                Unload Me
                MsgBox ("Welcome " + u + ", :)")
                Exit Do
            ElseIf Username <> u And Password = p Then
                MsgBox "Username not matched", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
                Exit Do
            ElseIf Username = u And Password <> p Then
                If Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail" Then
                    MsgBox "Your account is blocked", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value < 2 Then
                    MsgBox "Invalid password", vbCritical
                    Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4) + 1
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4) + 1
                    Cells(i, 3).Value = "fail"
                    'Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
                    Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
        If Username <> u And Password <> p Then MsgBox "Username & Password not match", vbCritical + vbOKCancel
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Keep in mind though, this is just a demonstrator. In practice, the message alert shouldn't so clearly spell out whether the mistake was on user id, or on password, or on both.

Comment: Hi Curious, Thanks for the very informative reply :). i have replaced the the 5th condition outside of the IF, however i was thrown the 5th condition even if username and password matches. what other solutions that you have ?

Comment: hi Ang Weien, if u have nested correctly, then it shouldn't throw any error. add your whole code block to the question. i will take a look

Comment: That code has the same problem as I suspect the OP's code has - if the username isn't the one entered by the user and the password for the user doesn't match the one for the other user then the `MsgBox "Neither Password nor Username matched"` is executed.  (And what sort of security system tells a user when they have entered a password that belongs to some other user, i.e. `MsgBox "Username not matched"`?)

Comment: If you get rid of the `ElseIf Username <> u And Password = p Then` and `ElseIf Username <> u And Password <> p Then` sections (neither of which should be there in a good security test - you should never reveal information re another user to the user attempting to login) then the code will probably work.  All you need to do is add in a flag to say whether the login was successful, although that might already be happening in `clr`.

Comment: yes Ang Weien, once your code runs smoothly, keep in mind the good advise from YowE3K

Comment: added in my question, @YowE3K im not familar with login flag tho. if i have that then all the elseif wonth be needed??. im just planning to hide the cells at the login page and hide the sheet after login.

Comment: @AngWeien By a "login flag" I just meant a boolean variable that you set to `False` before the loop (and set to `True` once you have processed something in the loop) and after the loop you can see whether you need to do any further processing (e.g. to say that the login failed).

Comment: try now Ang Weien? the last condition should have been outside the `Do While` loop

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks alot for solving it @curious :)